# Can I enter Switzerland from Vietnam with a German residence permit?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, vietnamese-citizens, zrh

I am a Vietnamese with a German residence permit.
I'm going to fly from Vietnam to Zurich Airport in Switzerland then take the train from Zurich to my destination city in Germany.
Will I have any trouble when entering Switzerland?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, holders of residence permits from any Schengen member state are allowed to *pass through* other member states on their way to the member state that issued the residence permit.

This holds even if you have exhausted the 90-of-every-180-days travel in the rest of the Schengen area that the residence permit usually allows you: see paragraph 6.5(a) of the [Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32016R0399).

(There's an exception if you're on Switzerland's national watch list of travelers they absolutely don't want ever -- but that is extremely rare, and not worth worrying about unless you already know you're on such a list).

Comment: " are allowed to pass through other member states" They can visit too.

Comment: @Crazydre: Yes, under certain conditions that don't all apply to transiting.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=VN&AR=DE&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CH&selDest=Switzerland&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Germany for a maximum stay of 90 days [within 180 days]

So yes, you can enter Switzerland with your passport and German residence permit.

Answer (score -3):

Since you have a German residency permit, you have the right of movement within the Schengen area, of which Switzerland is a member. But for such questions, it is usually better to ask the airlines you're flying with, as they are the ones with the definite answer: remember that they are the ones who would have to fly you back to Vietnam, and get fined, if they let you fly without checking.

The airlines have an up-to-date database. Call them and check.

Comment: The airlines use Timatic, to which everyone has access. -1 from me.